# Does delete[] work slower than new[]?

Tags: c++, vector, heap-memory

I've been running tests using gprof on a simple version of a vector which allocates memory on the heap (without actually being dynamic - tests purposes only). The thing is that looking at the result I see there's a huge difference between the 'new[]' and the 'delete[]' - given that I actually insert values to the vector (using the [] operator). 
Doing the above, I got results like:

```
%   cumulative   self              self     total           
  time   seconds   seconds    calls   s/call   s/call  name    
  0.92      0.55      0.01        1     5.03     5.03  MyVector::~MyVector()
  0.00      0.55      0.00        1     0.00     0.00  MyVector::MyVector(int)
```

But If I just allocate memory and delete it, without actually inserting values to the vector, they
work just as fast:

```
%   cumulative   self              self     total           
time   seconds   seconds    calls  ms/call  ms/call  name    
0.00      0.09     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  MyVector::MyVector(int)
0.00      0.09     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  MyVector::~MyVector()
```

My guess is that when using 'new[]' the compiler (gcc in my case) doesn't really allocate the memory, and only when it needs to it does that (like when using []). And when it needs to destroy the object, it has
to de-allocate all the memory which was allocated during each access (using []).

I couldn't find any documentation for this - and maybe there's something I'm not aware of. I'd be happy
if someone will share his knowledge regarding this issue.

Edit: I added the code I used. 
Thanks for all the answers so far:

```
class MyVector
{
public:

        MyVector(int size) { _data = new int[size]; };
        ~MyVector() { delete[] _data; } ;

        int& operator[](int index) { return _data[i]; };

 private:
       int* _data;
       int _size;     
 };


    And the test:

int main() {

      MyVector v(1000000);

      for (int j = 0 ; j<20000 ; ++j) {
        for (int i = 0; i<1000000; ++i) {
          v[i]= i; //If i remove this line, destructor and constructor work just as fast
        }
     }

      return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: `[]` doesn't insert or allocate anyting....

Comment: If `calls 1` means you're only calling those functions once during your test, I'd question the value of those figures. Call them a few thousand times at least.

Comment: what do all these numbers mean?

Comment: @Default - one answer is that the numbers are described [here](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/as/gprof.html#SEC5). Another is that the numbers are meaningless with a sample size of 1.

Comment: Isn't that all about comparing apples with bananas??

Comment: With 1 sample those numbers are very uncertain, but if they're anywhere near correct, 5 ms is a *lot* of time to spend freeing a block of memory.  What are you storing in the vector?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. `new[]` does not really allocate memory immediately on all systems. On Linux for example, you get a pointer back that points to memory that will only get allocated if you try to actually use it. So:

```
something = new[N];
delete[] something;
```

where `something` is a pointer to a built-in type, is pretty much a no-op.

(This could be breaking standards conformance, because `new` is supposed to throw when no more memory is available (or return NULL in the nothrow version). But that's how it is; Linux pretty much treats this as if it had infinite memory.)

Note that this only applies to built-in types because they are not getting default-constructed with `new[]`, unless you ask for it. Other types have their default ctor called, and thus the memory is accessed. In order to test, try just accessing the last element:

```
something = new[N];
something[N-1] = some_Value;
delete[] something;
```

Does this change your gprof results? If yes, then the delayed allocation is most probably the cause of what you're seeing.

Comment: Correct but meaningless. `new[]` does not allocate real memory, but it absolutely does allocate address space. And the expensive part is finding a _contiguous_ chunk of address space. Real memory isn't mapped contiguously anyway, due to the MMU.

Comment: @MSalters Are you sure that address space allocation is not delayed until use? The pointer you get back initially can be mapped to anywhere later.

Comment: Unless the latest standard changed things (I haven't worked much in C++ lately), a call to the array-based `new` operator is required to invoke the default constructor for each element in the array.  This requires that it not only find (or construct) a contiguous address space but that it also reference the new objects to construct them.  That sounds a lot like _allocation_ to me.

Comment: @D.Shawley Don't you only get that with `something = new[N]();` (note the `()` at the end.)

Comment: @NikosC. : absolutely. The pointer cannot be mapped to anywhere, because the pointer must point to an address range which cannot overlap any other address range. If `0x1040` is already allocated, `new[]` may not return `0x1000` for aarray of size  `0x50`. That would cause a 16 byte overlap.

Comment: @D.Shawley: That's true for types which have default constructors, but `int` for instance doesn't have a constructor.

Comment: @MSalters Hm, makes sense. I changed the answer to suggest a test case for this, by writing to the last element. If that won't change the results, then you're most probably right.

Comment: @MSalters: finding contiguous address space is *potentially* expensive. Often it's dirt cheap, you slice some off a block previously allocated from the OS (likely via an allocation list based on the size requested). Even within the system call there's a reasonable chance that for a program that does all of one allocation, the OS will find address space in the first place it looks. I don't think there's enough information in the question to say whether we'd expect this particular allocation to be a bad case or a good case. We don't even know how big it is.